# Cookie is not being set in the browser

Tags: node.js, reactjs, authentication, cookies, jwt

In my codebase using NodeJS (with express as the framework), I'm using jwt for authentication. Upon successful authentication, the jwt token is attached to the response as a cookie. This is the handler code for the same

```
const createJSONWebToken = id => {
    return jwt.sign({id}, process.env.JWT_SECRET, {
        expiresIn: process.env.JWT_EXPIRY
    })
}

const sendJSONWebToken = (user, statusCode, res) => {
    const token = createJSONWebToken(user._id);
    const cookieOptions = {
        expiresIn: new Date(Date.now() + 30*24*60*60*1000)
    }
    
    res.cookie('jwt', token, cookieOptions);
    console.log(res);
    user.password = undefined;
    res.status(statusCode).json({
        status: 'Success',
        token,
        data: {
            user
        }
    })
}

exports.login = async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        const email = req.body.email;
        const password = req.body.password;
        const user = await User.findOne({ email }).select('+password');
        if(user && await user.correctPassword(password, user.password)) {
            sendJSONWebToken(user, 200, res);
        }
        else {
            res.status(200).json({
                status: 'Failure',
                message: 'Either email or password is incorrect'
            })
        }
    }
    catch(err) {
        res.status(200).json({
            status: 'Failure',
            message: err.message
        })
    }
}
```

Now, I'm sending a login POST request from my React front-end to the API, and the request is successful as well, yet still, I can't find the cookie in the applications tab of Chrome Developer Tools.
Furthermore, I also tried to `console.log(req.cookies)` in the subsequent requests and the result was the logging of undefined

The following is the front-end code for logging in

```
login = async () => {
        const email = document.getElementById('email').value;
        const password = document.getElementById('password').value;
        const credentials = {
            email, 
            password
        }

        const res = await axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/v1/users/login', credentials);
        console.log(res);
    }
```

What is the problem here? Why is the cookie not being set and how do I fix this

Comment: Do you want to retrive JWT token or you need to set cookie?

Comment: @PrasannaBrabourame I wish to set the cookie in the browser so that the token can be used in subsequent requests to the API

Comment: For subsequent request api you can able to handle by capturing headers with names ‘x-access-token’ or ‘Authorization.’ It has Bearer token value

Comment: Next time you run the request, try checking the `Set-Cookie` response header in the Network tab. It may have an icon that you can hover over to get the error.

Comment: @Calvin The response is correct and has the Set-Cookie header with the correct value. It's just that the cookie is not being set in my browser due to Cross-Origin-Resource-Sharing (as my NodeJS server and my React app are running on 2 different ports)